# deleting a pointer to a sorted string array gives me an error after running

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was practicing sorting and pointers for my alg class - its a simple program that asks a user to give an input on the number of names one wishes to input, then asks for those names, then sorts it out.

```
string *sortname(string array[], int number)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number - 1; i++)
    {
        int smallestIndex = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < number; j++)
        {
            if (array[smallestIndex] > array[j])
                smallestIndex = j;
        }
        swap(array[i], array[smallestIndex]);
    }

    return array;
}

int main()
{
cout << "enter the number of names you wish to enter." << endl;

int number;
cin >> number;

string *array = new string[number];

for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    cout << "enter name #" << i+1 << ":";
    cin >> array[i];
}

cout << "the names are: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    cout << array[i] << endl;
}

string *sorted; 
sorted = sortname(array, number);

cout << "the sorted names are: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    cout << sorted[i] << endl;
}

delete[] array;
delete[] sorted;

return 0;
}
```

I am aware that the function `sortname` can be set to `void` and return nothing, but I just wanted to try returning (for the sake of practice).
However, when I add a `delete[] sorted` in the end, the console crashes after it lists out the sorted name. If I just `delete[] array` it works fine, although the sorted should be deleted as well... any hints?

Comment: Because you're double deleting the same array.

Comment: ah i see, thanks for that, now it makes perfect sense!

Comment: I dont have to do anything with the pointer sorted, since the main array has been deleted. thanks for the help

Comment: Just pass `std::vector<std::string>` and return by value. That would be a good practice and will not have this issue

Answer (score 3):

`sortname` returns a copy of its `array` argument.

So, `sorted` points to the same array as `array`. Therefore once `array` is deleted, the `sorted` points to that deleted array. It no longer points to a valid object.

Deleting a pointer that doesn't point to an object has undefined behaviour.

---

A rule of thumb: You need exactly one delete for each new. You've called new once. Calling delete twice is more than once.

Another rule of thumb: Don't ever allocate memory directly. You could have used `std::vector` instead.